# browser horizontal scroller showing when not needed

Tags: html, css

Example link: (LINK REMOVED SOLVED THANKS GUYS)

When the page is first loading we see a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the browser. this scroller bar stays for like 2-5 seconds and disapears.

There is no need for it on my current resolution so i dont see why it is showing up.

This occurs in Firefox 4, Internet explorer 7 & 8
This DOESNT happen in Google Chrome or Safarie.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried putting overflow:hidden on the wrapper?

Comment: just tried. used overflow-x... didnt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is being caused by some Javascript on the page. If you disable JS you'll notice that the problem doesn't occur.

It's hard to tell exactly which bit is causing the problem since it rights itself quite quickly. My guess is that it's the text-scroller with the title "Événements à venir" that's causing the issue.

Comment: ya i see that taking js off the scroller bug stops. so ill keep looking a bit. its not "evenements" turned it off and its still doing it.

Comment: In that case my guess would be that it's the Facebook script. That seems to be the last thing to load and it looks like the issue vanished once the facebook script finishes.

Comment: ur right facebook is the faulty one. thanks ill see what i can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should help you:

```
    html, body { overflow: hidden; }
```

This is placed in the CSS.

Comment: ya but wouldnt that prevent a horiz scroller to show up if the page is really that small? right now it shows up for 2-5 secs then disapears. if i resize the page to make it needed it shows up again. i just want to avoid that 2-5 secondes where its shows for no reason.

Comment: I think it doesn't, but you should try. That is the only way to know for sure I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use css3

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with JS.. You could use

```
html, body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

and make sure you display the scrollbar when you resize to something less than min-width.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width() < (your_container_width or fixed width that you define) )
    $(html).css("overflow-x","scroll");
    $(body).css("overflow-x","scroll");
});
```